# Running python files

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am working on pyqt4 and python26 application.I created forms using qt designer (.ui files).
I converted them to .py and .pyc files.But when i try to run .py file ,python command line comes and goes within a second,the form (corresponding .ui file) cannot be seen...what can be the problem??

this is my code:(.py file)

```
from DlgAbout_ui import Ui_DlgAbout

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

import resources

class DlgAbout(QDialog, Ui_DlgAbout):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.logo.setPixmap( QPixmap( ":/icons/faunalia_logo.png" ) )

        text = self.txt.toHtml()
        text = text.replace( "$PLUGIN_NAME$", "RT Sql Layer" )
        self.txt.setHtml(text)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, don't use:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
```

Instead:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
```

And reference the modules explicitly.

```
class DlgAbout(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_DlgAbout):
```

etc.

In your code, all you've done is defined a dialog box. You haven't defined any main application to run, or any way to show the dialog box.

For an example, here's a basic main *application* to run:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys


class MyMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.form_widget = FormWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.form_widget)


class FormWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(FormWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Button!")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    foo = MyMainWindow()
    foo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This defines a main window, and a form (Which MyMainWindow sets up, as you can see).
I then check if this is the main file being run (`if __name__ == "__main__":`), and I start the application (The `app = QtGui.QApplication([])`, create the main window, and **show the main window**.

In your case, you could define a main application like I did, and make it alert your QDialog.

Comment: when i declare  QDialog.__init__(self,parent) in  class FormWidget(QtGui.QWidget):  ,it gives error saying NameError: global name 'QDialog' is not defined...... help me out...

Comment: Try `QtGui.QDialog`. You'll also need to change the pixmap to `QtGui.QPixmap`. That's what I meant about referencing the modules explicitly ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your python code just imports some modules and then defines a new class. It doesn't do anything with the class it has defined, though. In other words, once Python is done creating the new class, it is finished, and it exits.

I don't know PyQT at all, but most likely you need to start the GUI's main loop, and also instantiate an instance of your new class and pass it to PyQT.